# Get default case class arguments via Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Does shapeless provide a type class/macro that summons a `HList` containing the default values for all parameters of a case class?

Let's say we have this case class:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int = 18)
```

Then I would like to get such a `HList`:

```
None :: Some(() => 18) :: HNil
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default parameters is implemented over synthetic methods.
Try it trait.  https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/default.scala

```
import shapeless.Default

case class User(name: String, age: Int = 18)
val d = Default[User]
println(d())
```

Out:

```
None :: Some(18) :: HNil
```

Comment: Default values get compiled to methods that produce the value. In my example scala would create a method that returns 18. I thought shapeless may provide references to those methods. I've tried to implement such a macro on my own but I did not find an api that allows the macro writer to somehow get those generated methods even though it should theoretically be possible...

Comment: @Aki use it https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/default.scala

Comment: That seems to be what i was looking for. May you write that as a separate answer so I could accept it?